# How to use Python to prove that a radical expression is the root of a cubic polynomial

Tags: python, sympy

The given polynomial is

```
p = Poly(x**3-x**2-2*x+1, x) # and a root as radical expression:
rt = 1/3 + (-7/2 - 21*sqrt(3)*I/2)**(1/3)/3 + (-7/2 + 21*sqrt(3)*I/2)**(1/3)/3
```

substituting the root into the polynomial gives (simplified):

```
expr = 7*(-1 - 3*sqrt(3)*I)**(2/3)*(-1 + 3*sqrt(3)*I)**(1/3)/18 - \
7*2**(2/3)*(-7 + 21*sqrt(3)*I)**(1/3)/18 - \
7*2**(2/3)*(-7 - 21*sqrt(3)*I)**(1/3)/18 + \
7*(-1 - 3*sqrt(3)*I)**(1/3)*(-1 + 3*sqrt(3)*I)**(2/3)/18
```

but there is no way to make python show that this expression is zero:

```
expr == 0 # False
```

But :

```
expr.evalf()  # gives -0.e-131 - 0.e-132*I
```

Comment: I think you'd have to test if the expression is smaller than a threshold you define

Comment: Check this: [How to make sympy simplify a radical expression equaling zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62745153/how-to-make-sympy-simplify-a-radical-expression-equaling-zero)

Comment: verifying the minimal polynomial gives _x, this is the minimal polynomial of zero, so the problem is solved, moreover the minimal polynomial of the root gives the given polynomial so that's also OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function `minpoly` to compute the minimal polynomial of an algebraic expression:

```
In [71]: rt = S(1)/3 + (-S(7)/2 - 21*sqrt(3)*I/2)**(S(1)/3)/3 + (-S(7)/2 + 21*sqrt(3)*I/2)**(S(1)/3)/3

In [72]: rt
Out[72]: 
        _______________       _______________
       ╱   7   21⋅√3⋅ⅈ       ╱   7   21⋅√3⋅ⅈ 
    3 ╱  - ─ - ───────    3 ╱  - ─ + ─────── 
1   ╲╱     2      2       ╲╱     2      2    
─ + ─────────────────── + ───────────────────
3            3                     3         

In [73]: minpoly(rt)
Out[73]: 
 3    2          
x  - x  - 2⋅x + 1
```

That shows that this is a root of the polynomial that you showed. In general of `r` is a root of a polynomial `p` then `minpoly(r)` is a polynomial that divides `p`.

We can also use `minpoly` to prove that the expression after substituting the root into the polynomial is zero:

```
In [74]: p = x**3-x**2-2*x+1

In [75]: p.subs(x, rt)
Out[75]: 
                                                                           2                                                  3 
          _______________   ⎛        _______________       _______________⎞    ⎛        _______________       _______________⎞  
         ╱   7   21⋅√3⋅ⅈ    ⎜       ╱   7   21⋅√3⋅ⅈ       ╱   7   21⋅√3⋅ⅈ ⎟    ⎜       ╱   7   21⋅√3⋅ⅈ       ╱   7   21⋅√3⋅ⅈ ⎟  
    2⋅3 ╱  - ─ + ───────    ⎜    3 ╱  - ─ - ───────    3 ╱  - ─ + ─────── ⎟    ⎜    3 ╱  - ─ - ───────    3 ╱  - ─ + ─────── ⎟  
1     ╲╱     2      2       ⎜1   ╲╱     2      2       ╲╱     2      2    ⎟    ⎜1   ╲╱     2      2       ╲╱     2      2    ⎟  
─ - ───────────────────── - ⎜─ + ─────────────────── + ───────────────────⎟  + ⎜─ + ─────────────────── + ───────────────────⎟  
3             3             ⎝3            3                     3         ⎠    ⎝3            3                     3         ⎠  

                       
        _______________
       ╱   7   21⋅√3⋅ⅈ 
  2⋅3 ╱  - ─ - ─────── 
    ╲╱     2      2    
- ─────────────────────
            3          

In [76]: minpoly(p.subs(x, rt))
Out[76]: x
```

Here the minimal polynomial is `x` whose only root is zero.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(field_theory)
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html#sympy.polys.numberfields.minpoly

Comment: I already found out this answer (see my comment to Alex) but for the reading public this answer should be marked as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is floating point precision. A lot of the operations in your equation are going to be just a little off, especially for 2/3 or 1/3 which have infinte decimals. This is explained in answers such as this one [How to avoid floating point errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473770/how-to-avoid-floating-point-errors). To avoid the issue either truncate the result to within a specific number of decimal points maybe using `round`?

```
round(float_num, num_of_decimals)
```

And then evaluate whether that equals zero.

You may be tempted to kick the can down the road and use `Decimal` which has a higher precision but I doubt you'll get a flat zero even using that, some of those operations just don't yield numbers with a finite number of decimals so some quantity will be lost somewhere and you'll end up with a result very close to zero but not really it.

Do you **need** 131 or 132 decimal point precision for it to be zero?